# Rendering a Datatables column to ignore letter and sort by number

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having trouble using `jQuery` `Datatables` to sort data.

I have a table that has many columns. The column I want to sort is `Document Number`. Some document numbers have an A at the start and some don't. I am trying to sort these in descending order without regard to that letter `A`.

Currently the data looks like this:

```
A83052
A83030
A83019
A08565
A08554
A08542
A08455
 08500
 08365
 08345
 00098
```

But I want it sorted as follows:

```
A83052
A83030
A83019
A08565
A08554
A08542
 08500
A08455
 08365
 08345
 00098
```

I do have to leave the A there, however, since it is part of the `Document number`.

Here is my code:

```
j$("table[id$=policyBlock]").DataTable({
    "order": [[0, 'desc']],
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false
});
```

What I tried to do is add the following after the "bInfo" field:

```
 "columnDefs": [ {
     "targets": 0,
     "render": function( data, type, row ) {
         return type=="sort" ? data.replace(/\D/g,'') : data;
      }
  }]
```

The list then ordered itself as so:

```
 00098
 08365
 08500
A83019
A08565
A83030
A08554
A83052
A08455
 08345
A08542
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You can set `data-order` attribute for table cell and `Datatable` will order by this attribute. Your table cell should look like:

```
<td data-order="08542">A08542</td>
```

Read more: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

```js
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]], 
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="83052">A83052</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="83030">A83030</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="83019">A83019</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08565">A08565</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08554">A08554</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08542">A08542</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08455">A08455</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08500">08500</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08365">08365</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="08345">08345</td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="00098">00098</td>>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. We have millions of document numbers, so we can't attach a fixed number to every single one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DavidTarvin no fixed numbers. Just remove leading `A` from document number for `data-order` attribute.

Comment: @DavidTarvin try snippet in my answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to get that working could be to add a hidden column where the letter `A` is stripped off.

This is mentioned as an example in the docs for the [`columns.orderData` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "justNum-pre": a => parseFloat(a.replace(/\D/g, "")),
  "justNum-asc": (a, b) => a - b,
  "justNum-desc": (a, b) => b - a
});

const table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    type: 'justNum',
    targets: 0
  }]
});
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/mu955vq2/). Things might be different if you're using serverside though...